# Difference between prunings in git

Tags: git

Originally, I wanted to delete a remote branch.

```
git push --delete <branchname>
```

... did it for me. However, I don't get the difference between the other commands:

```
git push --prune ...
git prune ...
```

What are these for? The manual does not help me since it sounds similar and I would have expected them to do what I initially wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git prune` acts on your *local* repository, and it removes *objects* (e.g. commits and files that are no longer reachable from any branch or tag, or from `HEAD`). `git push --prune` acts on the *remote* repository, and it removes *branches* that do not exist locally (be *really* careful with this command, as it will delete all branches that you've never checked out locally; if a branch is known to your local repo only as a remote branch, it'll be deleted remotely).

Comment: Okay, thank you — but my local non-existing branch that I wanted to delete remotely (as well) wasn't deleted by `git push --prune` ... ? `git push --delete` did it then.

Comment: Did you actually delete it locally first?

Comment: Yes, I used `git branch -d <branchname>` ... should it have worked then? The branch was gone when looking at `git branch`

Comment: @Xiphias: I just happened to do this myself, and `git branch -d` followed by `git push --prune` worked (all too well, as it also deleted a bunch of branches that I wanted to keep, but that I hadn't checked out locally).